# GAE/python: How to parse multipart data file from Cloud Storage (GCS)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading file to GCS (input file from webform) by following gae/python code:-

```
fx = self.request.body_file
gcs_file = gcs.open(_GCS_BUCKET_NAME + "new_file_name", 'w')
gcs_file.write(fx.read())
```

I am able to retrieve this uploaded data from GCS with following code

```
gcs_file = gcs.open(_GCS_BUCKET_NAME + "new_file_name", 'r')
self.response.write(gcs_file.read())
```

Since the uploaded data is multiform data, how do I extract original file name, and original file (binary data) itself from gcs_file.read() ?

Comment: Google has designed a different pathway for you to upload files to GCS using GAE than the one you are currently using. Read this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage

Comment: I understand this pathway. However, does python have any inbuilt routine to split multipart data in my situation?

Comment: I have not used it at all, but try the CGI python library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html). As an aside though, can you give me your reasons for not using the standard upload method for GAE? I've encountered an almost unshakeable determination in many people to not upload using the designed mechanism, but I can never understand why...

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file in GCS with its original file name

or

You can create a small DataStore DB where with an entity having the data of your original file name and a reference to your file in GCS

Why should the original binary be different?

If you have managed to download it from GCS you can verify the binary is actually the same.

Comment: My main hurdle is how do I split multipart data into a file (with original filename that is already contained in multipart data). I agree and understand what you are saying, but my issue is not there.